# GHUnit CLI Build: Availability.h errors

Tags: xcodebuild, gh-unit

I am trying to do a command line build of a GHUnit target which builds fine inside Xcode.  I am running the following command to build:

> GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target
>   BasicBrowserUnitTest -configuration
>   Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.0 build

It gets along pretty nice, until it finds an error in Availability.h, an SDK header:

> /Xcode4
>   GM/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h:56:42:
>   error: operator '<' has no left
>   operand

Obviously, I haven't made any changes to Apple's stuff, why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I wasn't specifying the correct SDK version:

> GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target
>   BasicBrowserUnitTest -configuration
>   Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.0 build

Needed to be:

> GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target
>   BasicBrowserUnitTest -configuration
>   Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.3
>   build

Or in this case, the latest SDK version.